# How to add cocoapod files to git hub in ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoapods

How to add cocoapod files to git hub in ios

I created a project with google maps using cocoapod file it is working fine .

But after pushing to git hub I am is facing some issues any can help me...

Comment: What kind of issue you are facing?

Comment: whats your issue **facing some issues**

Comment: After pushing to git  if code is clone from another machine it is showing pod file is not found.

Comment: do you hava a .gitignore file in your repo. If you have a git ignore it could be the cases that it contains cocopod and therefore exclude those files from your repo

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 strategies when working with CocoaPods and source control: It comes down to deciding whether or not to check your Pods directory into git. See the [CocoaPods documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) for some guidance.

In your case, it looks like the choice was to *not* include the Pods directory, so after cloning the git repository, you should run `pod install` to install the google-maps pod.